# Terminal three to terminal two in Dubai airport. How do I transfer from one terminal to another?

Tags: transit, dxb, emirates, flydubai

I arrive in Dubai at terminal 3 and have an onward flight from terminal 2 on  Fly Dubai to Bucharest.  How do I transfer to terminal two. I will have my boarding pass with me for this onward flight.

Answer (score 2):

- Step 1. Get off the plane.
- Step 2. Walk your way to the security / metal detectors
- Step 3. Walk upto the transfer desk.
- Step 4. You will be directed to a bus.
- Step 5. Get on the bus.
- Step 6. Travel to Terminal 2.
- Step 7. Get off the bus.
- Step 8. Proceed to your gate for FlyDubai
- Step 9. Enjoy your flight.

Comment: Step 9: Board the Airplane. Step 10: Enjoy your flight :D